# Como configurar a resolução de módulos no arquivo tsconfig.json para utilizar a biblioteca ts-node em Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

Olá, estou criando uma API em typescript e a estrutura do meu projeto é a seguinte:

```
api
| - src
    | - index.ts
    | - server.ts
| - package.json
| - tsconfig.json
```

Dentro de `api/src/server.ts` eu tenho uma servidor simples usando o [express](https://expressjs.com):

```js
import Express from 'express';

export class Server {
  static async new(): Promise<Server> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      const server = new Server()
      await server.listen()
      resolve(server)
    })
  }

  private _express!: Express

  constructor() {
    this._express = Express()
    this._express.get('/', (_, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));
  }

  async listen(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this._express.listen(3000, () => {
        resolve(console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
      })
    })
  }
}
```

E dentro de `api/src/index.ts` eu crio uma instância desse servidor e inicio a API:

```js
import { Server } from '@/server';

Server
  .new()
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

No meu arquivo `api/tsconfig.json` eu fiz as configurações de `baseUrl` e `path` assim como é definido na documentação do [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url):

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
  },
}
```

E para rodar a aplicação, estou usando a biblioteca [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node). Teoricamente, não há mais configurações que eu deva fazer para que seja possível fazer a resolução de módulos, ou seja, no arquivo `api/src/index.ts` eu deveria conseguir encontrar o módulo `@/server` mas o projeto está me dando o seguinte erro:

[image: erro de resolução]

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Existe alguma configuração que deva ser feita para que eu possa fazer a resolução de módulos como está no projeto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usar esse tsconfig aqui:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",  
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true

  }

}
```

Perceba que estou pedindo para ele compilar a pastar ./src e jogar o resultado na pasta ./dist (é normal fazer isso para separa o código ts do compilado js. Dessa forma mude o script do seu package.json para dar star na dist:

```
 "scripts": {

    ...
    "start": "node ./dist/index.js"
    ...

 }
```

Tente isso, veja se funciona.

Comment: kra... eu to caçano isso a um tempão... vlw!